# Initialization error when compiling code with three equation containing array

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, jmodelica

I am trying to prepare a modelica code to understand array and for loop.
When I am compiling the code, I get following error.

The initialization problem is inconsistent due to the following equation: 0 != 1 = 1.0 - I[0]
Error in initialization. Storing results and exiting.
Use -lv=LOG_INIT -w for more information.
Simulation process failed. Exited with code -1.

I have tried to adjust array numbers to see if this solves. Could not trace the reason why the code is failing.

```
class flu
    parameter Real beta = 10.0/(40*8*24);
    parameter Real gamma= 3.0/(15*24);
    parameter Real dt = 0.1;
    parameter Real D  = 30;
    parameter Integer N_t = integer(D*24/dt);
    parameter Integer array = integer(N_t*dt);
    //parameter Real time[array];
    Real S[array] ;
    Real I[array] ;
    Real R[array] ;

initial equation
    S[0] = 50;
    I[0] = 1;
    R[0] = 0;

equation
    for n in 0:(array-1) loop
    S[n+1] = S[n] - dt*beta*S[n]*I[n];
    I[n+1] = I[n] + dt*beta*S[n]*I[n] - dt*gamma*I[n];
    R[n+1] = R[n] + dt*gamma*I[n];
    end for;

annotation(
    __OpenModelica_simulationFlags(lv = "LOG_STATS", outputFormat = "mat", s = "dassl"));end flu;
```

I am expecting to get three curves as a result .

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a few things wrong here. First of all, it seems OpenModelica does not output the index of the equation so the debugger can be opened.

But more importantly, you are setting

```
I[0] = 1
```

`I[1]` is the first index in Modelica... I don't know why this wouldn't give any warning in OpenModelica. Probably some edge case in an if equation that never triggers and thus no warning/error in this case.

```
class flu
    parameter Real beta = 10.0/(40*8*24);
    parameter Real gamma= 3.0/(15*24);
    parameter Real dt = 0.1;
    parameter Real D  = 30;
    parameter Integer N_t = integer(D*24/dt);
    parameter Integer array = integer(N_t*dt);
    //parameter Real time[array];
    Real S[array] ;
    Real I[array] ;
    Real R[array] ;

equation
    S[1] = 50;
    I[1] = 1;
    R[1] = 0;

equation
    for n in 1:(array-1) loop
    S[n+1] = S[n] - dt*beta*S[n]*I[n];
    I[n+1] = I[n] + dt*beta*S[n]*I[n] - dt*gamma*I[n];
    R[n+1] = R[n] + dt*gamma*I[n];
    end for;
end flu;
```

Comment: - Since Open Modelica does not output the index of the equation, do you have any suggestion how to solve this equations?

Comment: I have tried to find & run the diff equation without arrays and it seems to solve the error.

Comment: Well, the code I posted is a working version of the code; I found the equation by looking in the generated C-files (it is also shown in the error-message you got that `1.0 - I[0]` gave unexpected results). Or you solve it like damu_d suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
class flu
    parameter Real beta = 10.0/(40*8*24);
    parameter Real gamma= 3.0/(15*24);


    Real S(start = 50) ;
    Real I(start = 1) ;
    Real R(start = 0) ;


equation
    der(S)= -beta*S*I;
    der(I)=(beta*S*I) - (gamma*I);
    der(R)=gamma*I;

annotation(
    __OpenModelica_simulationFlags(lv = "LOG_STATS", outputFormat = "mat", s = "dassl"));end flu;
```